# Does the Microchip USB-CDC driver buffer its output?

Tags: pic, usb, usb-device

I am trying to communicate between a computer and a PIC32 using the CDC device driver from Microchip application libraries. I am having an issue, where if I output a few sentences using `putrsUSBUSART()` I receive nothing. However if I append that with a loop that spams for example "test\r\n", I eventually receive them (and at least some of the sentences I wanted to see).

I am using minicom on a Linux box as my terminal program. If the CDC driver should not do that, I'll have to look at the host driver / terminal program next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are using an output call descended from or crafted in imitation of puts.  `puts()` is traditionally a *stream* function and so should not be expected to necessarily commit output until something occurs such as:

- it sees an end-of-line character
- it fills an internal buffer
- you decide to call fflush() on stdout

(and perhaps a few other related triggers which don't immediately come to mind)

---

As USB is a packetized interface, you could also have an unsuitable algorithm in the firmware for deciding when it's worthwhile to send a packet.

---

Finally, while the CDC-ACM driver should be vendor independent, the posix serial API by which application programs access it can be configured to a wide variety of behavior.  Terminal programs normally put it in a fairly raw and responsive mode, but if you end up writing your own client you will likely need some termios adjustments.  You can play with many of these settings from the command line using the `stty` program.

Comment: I love working with USB.  When its not working, you have to figure out if the problem is with the descriptor, your USB stack, the rest of your firmware, or the hardware.  The tools that can help you do this the best are often expensive! There's little that's more satisfying to me than to hear the GADUNK of a correctly enumerated USB peripheral.

Comment: Indeed (minus the consumer OS sound effects).  I've learned not to make a USB-connected board without also breaking out at least one UART... for the debug messages to figure out why the USB isn't working!

Comment: @varesa - out of curiosity, what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 1):

I always design stuff with at least one serial RS232 port. I strongly try to make this connected to the UART that the bootloader uses, if present.

Reasons:

1.) Because it can be used to debug other subsystems (USB included)

2.) Because it is a reliable port where I can download the firmware when nothing else works

Comment: The (dev-)board does have a serial port with level converter and a D9 connector. Maybe I should configure that to debug the bus I am trying to use to debug other stuff :D

Comment: I think you will see great benefit by doing that.